# access running scene in jni main.cpp ( cocos2d-x)

Tags: android-ndk, cocos2d-x

i want to access my scene in jni main.cpp but when i call `cocos2d::CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getRunningScene()` i could not get it! 
my code :

```
void Java_tehrannama_test_tehrannama2_zoomIn(JNIEnv* env, jobject thiz,jfloat s) {

__android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_DEBUG, "zoom1", "zooom");
    HelloWorld* helloworld = dynamic_cast&lt;HelloWorld*&gt;(cocos2d::CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getRunningScene());
    helloworld->zoomin(s);
    helloworld->center.x = helloworld->center.x -10000;
}
```

i have no other scene then helloworld.

Comment: May I know why you wanna do this??

Comment: i want to use sdk ui and interact between my cocos2d-x code and java code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i found the problem actually my mistake! my helloworld layer added as child of current scene and the solution is to tag helloworld when adding and then get it like :

```
HelloWorld* helloworld = dynamic_cast<HelloWorld*>(cocos2d::CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getRunningScene()->getChildByTag(1));
```